# Can you get a virus by controlling an Ubuntu OS system through TeamViewer?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, remote-access, teamviewer, remote-connection

Can you get a virus by controlling an Ubuntu OS system through TeamViewer or from their network or through shared copy (copy function from Windows to Ubuntu and vice versa) ?

I think the OS is freshly installed on it, but still would like to ask.

The controller PC uses Windows

Comment: You can get a virus/malware from any source. That said, finding such in a desktop Linux and being dumb enough to transfer and run is very unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A virus cannot reach through a TeamViewer connection to infect the
connected computer.

However, if you transfer an infected file to your computer and use it,
infection is quite possible. This goes for executable files, Office
documents, videos, music, PDF and perhaps others.